# Google Spreadsheet Add-On Grayed out

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've been working on an Add-On for our Company (It will only be used within the Domain).
This Add-on has been tested with several account through the "Test as Add-On" function within Google Apps Script.

When I've published this Add-on through the Cloud Console & G Suite Marketplace SDK with the needed OAuth ranges found in the script properties.

Installing the Add-On, no issue, authorize the add-on. Unfortunately when I want to use it in Spreadsheet it stays Grayed out:
[Add-on Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a2lfa.png)

(Updated) Menu code:

```
function onOpen(e)
{
  //console.log(`onOpen function called`);
  var menu = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createAddonMenu();
  if(e && e.authMode == ScriptApp.AuthMode.NONE){
    console.log(`Authmode is NONE`);
    menu.addItem('Welkom!', 'activateAddon');
    menu.addToUi();
  }else {
    console.log(`Authmode isn't none!: ${e.authMode}`);
    var properties = PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties();
    var activated = properties.getProperty('workflowStarted');
    console.log(`checking properties: ${activated}`);
    if(activated){
      console.log(`Properties of activation are true`);
      setMenu();
      //menu.addItem('start Menu', 'setMenu');
    }else {
      console.log(`Properties of activation are false`);
      menu.addItem('Activeer', 'activateAddon');
      menu.addToUi();
    }
  }
}

function onInstall(e)
{
  onOpen(e);
}
```

What am I missing or doing wrong?
(also logging doesn't give any errors)

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
As requested the version of the setMenu function, also updated the onOpen function as mentioned in the comments.

```
function setMenu()
{
  let ui = sa.getUi();
  let menu = ui.createAddonMenu();
  const ss = sa.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  let id = sa.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId();
  console.log(`creating menu for: ${id}`);

  //menu.addItem('Refresh Menu', 'setMenu');

  let type = ss.getSheetByName("OnethatcannotbeFound").getRange("A1").getValue();

  switch(type){

    case "Onderhoudsdocument":
      let countSys = ss.getSheetByName("OnethatcannotbeFound").getRange("A2").getValue();

      if(ss.getSheetByName("Voorblad").getRange("B3").getValue() == ""){
        menu.addSubMenu(ui.createMenu("Onderhoudsdocument")
          .addItem("Klantenkaart Koppelen", "maintenanceConnKlant"));
      }
      else{
        if(countSys == 0){
          menu.addSubMenu(ui.createMenu("Onderhoudsdocument")
            .addItem("Klantenkaart Wijzigen", "maintenanceChangeKlant")
            .addItem("Werkvoorbereiding", "maintenanceOpenWV"));
        }else{
          menu.addSubMenu(ui.createMenu("Onderhoudsdocument")
            .addItem("Klantenkaart Wijzigen", "maintenanceChangeKlant")
            .addItem("Werkvoorbereiding", "maintenanceOpenWV")
            .addSeparator()
            .addItem("Onderhoudsopties", "maintenanceOpenOH")
            .addSeparator()
            .addItem("Lijst uitgevoerd Onderhoud", "maintShowMaintList"));
        }
      }
      break;
    case "Calculatiesheet":
      if(ss.getSheetByName("Voorblad").getRange("C3").getValue() == ""){
        menu.addSubMenu(ui.createMenu("Calculatiesheet")
          .addItem("Klantenkaart Koppelen", "calcConnKlant"));
      }
      else {
        menu.addSubMenu(ui.createMenu("Calculatiesheet")
          .addItem("Klantenkaart Wijzigen", "calcChangeKlant")
          .addItem("Genereer Document", "calcGenerateDoc")
          .addItem("Wis Gegevens", "calcResetData"));
      }
      break;

    case "Urenregistratie":
      menu.addSubMenu(ui.createMenu("Urenregistratie")
        .addItem("Start Berekening", "hourStartCalc")
        .addItem("Invoeren Storingsdienst", "hourConsigAdd"));
      break;

    default:
      ui.alert("Oops", `Oh noos!\nIt seems something went wrong gathering information about your sheet type.\nPlease inform development through the contact page with the following message:\nError Gathering Info: ${type}`, ui.ButtonSet.OK);
      return;
  }

  menu.addSubMenu(ui.createMenu("Help")
    .addItem('Handleiding', 'gotoManual')
    .addItem('Contact', 'gotoContact'));

  menu.addToUi();

}
```

EDIT 2:
Script Range:

```
  "oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.container.ui",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.currentonly",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly",
    "https://mail.google.com/"
    ],
```

Marketplace UAuth:
[Marketplace OAuth](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cdUbf.png)

Comment: Add the `setMenu` declaration as well more details like the OAuth consent screen and the G Suite Marketplace settings. How complex is your add-on? Is it using librearies and/or advanced services? Have you already tried using Chrome in incognito mode with all the extensions disabled? Try to create a [mcve] and add the complete code to the question.

Comment: @Rubén, I've updated the post with the `setMenu` function, also the OAuth within the script and within the marketplace, What do you call complex, this one is created purely to assist with automation within spreadsheets we've created. I'm using another account (test account) to test the script / addon, this one has no extensions or plugins, with this one the _dry run_ works but the installed version isn't. I'll try to create a minimal version of the script to see if I can make this work.

Comment: I think that you should try to create a very simple addon (include a custom menu to do something simple like an alert, so the authotrization scopes are the minimum, also keep the G Suite Marketplace settings as simple as possible), If this simple add-on doesn't work then it will be very likely that the IT dept missed to whitelist something related to the G Suite Marketplace.

Comment: @Rubén, I've created a simple new Add-on like you mentioned and awaiting approval of our IT Department, when it's up I'll let you know the outcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took some time for my IT Department to react and look into it.
The simple Add-On I've created as suggested by @Rubén didn't work like the original one.
Now they've changed something within the Marketplace SDK (what, they can't tell me) and everything works now.
So it wasn't the code that made it gray out, but settings within our Domain Policy etc.
Thanks @Rubén for your time and support!